# Android :Quiz , how to use drawable value instead on assets

Tags: android

I want to pass value from drawable folder . I know the way how to pass value from draw able but have less knowledge to modify below code . In this code all players value are fetched from "Assets" . and I want to pass from drawable . drawable folder has two value , one is " player" folder and another is background image ,some icons. I am not sure about subfolder in drawable will work or not . If not then how I'll exclude background image , icons. I can pass drawable value using array like  player[] ={R.drawable.A, R.drawable.B....} . Still unable to modify this code . I am feeling really helpless :(

```
public class QuizGame extends Activity {

    //String used when logging error messages
    private static final String TAG = "QuizGame Activity";

    //Instance Variables
    private List<String> fileNameList; // player file names
    private List<String> quizPlayersList; // names of players in quiz
    private String correctAnswer; // current correct answer
    private int totalGuesses; // number of guesses
    private int correctAnswers; // number of correct guesses
    private int guessRows; // number of rows displaying choices
    private Random random; // random number generator
    private Handler handler; // used to delay loading of next player
    private Animation shakeAnimation; // animation for incorrect answers

    private TextView answerTextView;
    private TextView questionNumberTextView;
    private ImageView faceImageView;
    private TableLayout buttonTableLayout;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);



    fileNameList = new ArrayList<String>(); // list of image file names
    quizPlayersList =  new ArrayList<String>(); // players in quiz
    guessRows = 3; // defaulted to one row of choices
    random = new Random(); // initialize the random number generator
    handler = new Handler(); // used to perform delayed operations

    // get references to the GUI components
    questionNumberTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.questionNumberTextView);
    answerTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answerTextView);
    faceImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.faceImageView);
    buttonTableLayout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.buttonTableLayout);

    // set questionNumbers Text
    questionNumberTextView.setText(
            getResources().getString(R.string.question) + " 1 " +
            getResources().getString(R.string.of) + " 10");


    // load the shake animations used to animate incorrect answers
    shakeAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.incorrect_shake);
    shakeAnimation.setRepeatCount(3); // animation repeats 3 times

    // start a new quiz
    resetQuiz();

  } //end onCreate method

    // set up and start the next quiz
    private void resetQuiz(){

        // use the AssetManager to get the player image
        // file names for the app
        AssetManager assets = getAssets();
        fileNameList.clear(); // clear the list

        // get list of all player names in this region
        String[] paths = null;
        try {
            paths = assets.list("Players");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.e(TAG, "Error loading ", e);
        }

        for(String path : paths)
            fileNameList.add(path.replace(".jpg", ""));



        correctAnswers = 0; // reset number of correct answers
        totalGuesses= 0; // reset number of guesses
        quizPlayersList.clear(); // clear prior list of quiz countries

        // add 10 random file names to the quiz list
        int playerCounter = 1;
        int numberOfPlayers = fileNameList.size();

        while(playerCounter <= 10){

            int randomIndex = random.nextInt(numberOfPlayers);

            //get random file name
            String fileName = fileNameList.get(randomIndex);

            //if region is enabled and hasnt been chosen
            if(!quizPlayersList.contains(fileName)){
                quizPlayersList.add(fileName);
                ++playerCounter;
            }
        }

        loadNextPlayer(); //start quiz by loading next player


    }

    // after user guesses a correct player, load the next one
    private void loadNextPlayer(){

        //get the filename of the next flag and remove it from the list
        String nextImageName = quizPlayersList.remove(0);
        correctAnswer = nextImageName; //update correct answer

        answerTextView.setText(""); //clear the answerTextView

        //display the number of the current question in the quiz
        questionNumberTextView.setText(
                getResources().getString(R.string.question) + " " +
                (correctAnswers + 1) + " " +
                getResources().getString(R.string.of) + " 10");

        //extract the region from the next images name
        String region = "Players"; 

        //use AssetManager to load next image from assets folder
        AssetManager assets = getAssets(); // get apps Asset Manager
        InputStream stream; // used to read in player names

        try{

            //get an InputStream to the asset representing the next flag
            stream = assets.open(region + "/" + nextImageName + ".jpg");

            //load the asset as Drawable and display on the flagImageView
            Drawable flag = Drawable.createFromStream(stream, nextImageName);
            faceImageView.setImageDrawable(flag);
         }
        catch (IOException e){
            Log.e(TAG, "Error loading " + nextImageName, e);
        }

        //clear prior answer buttons from tablerows
        for (int row = 0; row < buttonTableLayout.getChildCount(); row++)
             ((TableRow) buttonTableLayout.getChildAt(row)).removeAllViews();

        Collections.shuffle(fileNameList); //shuffle file names

        //put the correct answer at the end of the fileNameList
        int correct = fileNameList.indexOf(correctAnswer);
        fileNameList.add(fileNameList.remove(correct));

        //get a reference to the LayoutInflator Service
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        // add 3, 6, or 9 answer Buttons based on the value of guessRows
        for (int row = 0; row < guessRows; row++){

            TableRow currentTableRow = getTableRow(row);

            //place Buttons in currentTableRow
            for (int column = 0; column < 3; column++){

                //inflate guess_button.xml to create new Button
                Button newGuessButton = 
                        (Button) inflater.inflate(R.layout.guess_button, null);

                //get player name and set it as newGuessButtons text
                String fileName = fileNameList.get((row * 3) + column);
                newGuessButton.setText(getPlayerName(fileName));

                //register answerButton listener to respond to clicks
                newGuessButton.setOnClickListener(guessButtonListener);
                currentTableRow.addView(newGuessButton);
            }

        }

        //randomly replace one Button with the correct answer
        int row = random.nextInt(guessRows);
        int column = random.nextInt(3);
        TableRow randomTableRow = getTableRow(row);
        String playerName = getPlayerName(correctAnswer);
        ((Button) randomTableRow.getChildAt(column)).setText(playerName);

    } // end loadNextPlayer method


    // return the specified TableRow
    private TableRow getTableRow(int row){

        return (TableRow) buttonTableLayout.getChildAt(row);
    }


    // parses the player file name and returns the player name
    private String getPlayerName(String name){

        return name.substring(name.indexOf('-') + 1).replace('-', ' ');
    }


    // method submitGuess called when user selects an answer
    private void submitGuess (Button guessButton){

        String guess = guessButton.getText().toString();
        String answer = getPlayerName(correctAnswer);
        ++totalGuesses; //increment the number of guesses made

        if (guess.equals(answer)){

            ++correctAnswers; // increment number of correct answers

            //display Correct answer in answerTextView 
            answerTextView.setText(answer + "!" );
            answerTextView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.correct_answer));

            disableButtons(); //disable all answer Buttons

            // if user has guessed 10 correct players
            if (correctAnswers == 10){

                //create new AlertDialog Builder
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                builder.setTitle(R.string.reset_quiz);

                //set the AlertDialogs message to display the game results
                builder.setMessage(String.format("%d %s, %.02f%% %s", totalGuesses,
                        getResources().getString(R.string.guesses),
                        (1000 / (double) totalGuesses),
                        getResources().getString(R.string.correct)));

                builder.setCancelable(false);

                //add reset quiz button
                builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.reset_quiz,
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                                resetQuiz();
                            } // end onClick
                        } // end anonymous inner class
                ); //end call to setPositiveButton

                // create AlertDialog from the Builder
                AlertDialog resetDialog = builder.create();
                resetDialog.show();

            } // end if

            else // answer is correct but game isnt over
            {
                //load the next flag after a one second delay
                handler.postDelayed(
                        new Runnable()
                        {
                            @Override
                            public void run(){
                                loadNextPlayer();
                            }
                        }, 1000); // 1000 milliseconds for 1 second delay


            } // end else
        } // end if

        else // answer was incorrect
        {
            //play the animation
            faceImageView.startAnimation(shakeAnimation);

            //display "Incorrect" in red
            answerTextView.setText(R.string.incorrect_answer);
            answerTextView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.incorrect_answer));

            guessButton.setEnabled(false); // disable the incorrect answer
        } 

    } // end submitGuess method


    // method to disable all answer Buttons
    private void disableButtons(){

        for (int row = 0; row < buttonTableLayout.getChildCount(); row++){
            TableRow tablerow = (TableRow) buttonTableLayout.getChildAt(row);

            for(int i = 0; i < tablerow.getChildCount(); i++){
                tablerow.getChildAt(i).setEnabled(false);
            }
        }
    }


    // create constants for each menu id
    private final int CHOICES_MENU_ID = Menu.FIRST;


    // called when the user accesses the options menu
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){

        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

        // add options to the menu
        menu.add(Menu.NONE, CHOICES_MENU_ID, Menu.NONE, R.string.choices);


        return true; // display the menu
    }

    // called when the user selects an option from the menu
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        // switch the menu id of the user selected option
        switch (item.getItemId())
        {
        case CHOICES_MENU_ID:
            //create a list of the possible number of answer choices
            final String[] possibleChoices = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.guessesList);

            //create an AlertDialog Builder and set its title
            AlertDialog.Builder choicesBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            choicesBuilder.setTitle(R.string.choices);

            //add possibleChoices items to the Dialog and set the
            // behavior when one of the items is clicked
            choicesBuilder.setItems(R.array.guessesList,
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {

                    // update guessRows to reflect user choice
                    guessRows = Integer.parseInt(possibleChoices[item].toString()) / 3;

                    resetQuiz();

                }
            });

            // create AlertDialog from the Builder
            AlertDialog choicesDialog = choicesBuilder.create();
            choicesDialog.show();

            break;
        } // end switch

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item); 

    }// end method onOptionsItemSelected
```